# if selecting country the currency should load based on the country

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Currency Type</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<select class="form-control m-b"ng-init="invoice.currencytype='inr'" 
name="currencytype" ng-model="invoice.currencytype" required>

<option value="all">Albania Lek - ALL </option>
<option value="afn">Afghanistan Afghani - AFN </option>
<option value="ars">Argentina Peso - ARS </option>
</select> 
</div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-6">
<i> <label>ALL</label>
<ng-if="(invoice.currencytype == 'all')"/></i>
<i><label>AFN</label>
<ng-if="(invoice.currencytype == 'afn')"/></i>
<i><label>ARS</label>
<ng-if="(invoice.currencytype == 'ars')"/></i>
</div>`
```

pls help in this if i select the Albania Lek - ALL on;y the label ALL should some but now am getting all the 3 currency like

ALL AFN ARS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does ng-if do? It's immediately closed. So you need to show something inside. You might want to try this:

```
<i ng-if="invoice.currencytype == 'all'"><label>ALL</label></i>
<i ng-if="invoice.currencytype == 'afn'"><label>AFN</label></i>
<i ng-if="invoice.currencytype == 'ars'"><label>ARS</label></i>
```

This way, the label and the `<i>` will only be shown when the currency is `all` or one of the other options.